# how to write test class for ContentVersion Trigger

Tags: trigger, code-coverage

Need help to write a test for the below **trigger**

```
trigger GFP_Update on ContentVersion (after insert) {

    if(trigger.new.get(0).Title == 'TestWebservice.csv'){

        GFP_ParseCSV.parseCSV1(trigger.new.get(0).VersionData.toString());

        //Make a @future method to update records
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of Test class you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an **ContentNote** or **ContentVersion** record in your test class and that would automatically create a **ContentVersion** record, hence, firing your `ContentVersion` trigger.

Sample code to create a **ContentNote** record is

```
// Insert a ContentNote record  
ContentNote cn = new ContentNote();
string body = 'Hello, World!';
cn = (ContentNote) TestFactory.createSObject(new ContentNote(Title='test note1',Content=Blob.valueOf(body.escapeHTML4())));

insert cn;
System.assert([Check the results you are expecting from your GPF_Parse CSV class here]);
```

and Viola!

P.S. [`TestFactory`](https://github.com/dhoechst/Salesforce-Test-Factory) is a test data generation class and you can find tons of examples on the internet on that.